# Birix 1C. Не выводиться картинка превью в компоненте

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем доброго дня! Кто может подсказать? Есть кастом компонент в шаблоне для Битрикса от Аспро. Есть компонент вывода новостей на главной странице. Когда выводишь его первый раз все работает как надо. Когда дублируешь его для вывода с другими новостями, то вместо превью выводятся заглушки. С чем может быть связана данная проблема ? Компонент один, вывод идентичный, изображения на странице разные )

Answer (score 0):

В итоге в шаблоне был корявый вывод, создал из базового компонента свой и все начало отображаться как надо. Шаблоны...